# Smooth sprite movement in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Hi I'm making a game in Swift with Sprite Kit and I'm wondering if there is a way to have a sprite have smooth movement. Currently I'm using the moveTo method in SKAction and the sprite gets to the target location in a set period of time - meaning that if the location is farther away, the sprite will get there faster. I'm wondering if there is a solid way of getting the sprite to accelerate to a maximum set speed and then slow down when getting to the location. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Pythagorean theorem to get the correct duration based on distance in order to get desired speed. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19126642/431271

as far as slowing at the end goes, you can do some quick built in easing methods like this:

```
var moveAction = SKAction.moveByX(moveX, y:moveY, duration:0.5);
moveAction.timingMode = SKActionTiming.EaseInEaseOut
node.runAction(moveAction)
```

And if you want other easing methods use libraries such as the one referenced **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21764087/431271)**